# PrincipalSearcher.FindByIdentitiy() memory leak

Tags: .net, directoryservices

In the [MSDN entry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345628%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) for `PrincipalSearcher.FindByIdentitiy()`, Gary Caldwell noted (at the bottom in Community Content) that a memory leak results from the use of this method because "the underlying implemenation uses `DirectorySearcher` and `SearchResultsCollection` but does not call dispose on the `SearchResultsCollection` as the document describes."  This leak also apparently results in the need to call an explicit `Dispose()` when using `PrincipalSearcher.FindAll()` or `PrincipalSearcher.FindOne()` as a workaround.

This entry was made for .NET 3.5, yet no mention of the problem is listed for .NET 4.0 and later.  Can anyone confirm if this issue has been fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick look with Reflector suggests that it's been fixed:
`System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ADStoreCtx`
`FindPrincipalByIdentRefHelper`:

```
DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(this.ctxBase);
SearchResultCollection results = null;
try
{
   ...
}
catch (COMException exception)
{
    throw ExceptionHelper.GetExceptionFromCOMException(exception);
}
finally
{
    searcher.Dispose();
    if (results != null)
    {
        results.Dispose();
    }
}
```